# Mixing solutions of sympy equation

Tags: sympy, solver

I'm solving an time depend equation that has the following form (finding the roots for \lambda):

```
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = sp.symbols(r't', real=True, positive=True)


eq = ...

print(repr(eq))
-\lambda**3 - 2*\lambda**2*t + 4*\lambda*t**4 - 8*\lambda*t**3 + 8*\lambda*t**2 - 8*\lambda*t + 4*\lambda + 8*t**3 - 16*t**2 + 8*t
```

Solving the equation and saving the roots to a list:

```
sol = sp.solve(eq)
e_list = [list(sol[i].values())[0] for i in range(len(sol))]
```

Showing their evolution explicitly:

```
x =e_list[0]
lam_x = sp.lambdify(t, x, modules=['numpy'])

x_vals = np.linspace(0.01, .9999, 1000, dtype=complex)
y_vals = np.around(lam_x(x_vals),decimals=5)

plt.plot(np.real(x_vals), np.real(y_vals),label='r1')


x =e_list[1]
lam_x = sp.lambdify(t, x, modules=['numpy'])

x_vals = np.linspace(0.01, .9999, 1000, dtype=complex)
y_vals = np.around(lam_x(x_vals),decimals=5)

plt.plot(np.real(x_vals), np.real(y_vals),label='r2')


x =e_list[2]
lam_x = sp.lambdify(t, x, modules=['numpy'])

x_vals = np.linspace(0.01, .9999, 1000, dtype=complex)
y_vals = np.around(lam_x(x_vals),decimals=5)

plt.plot(np.real(x_vals), np.real(y_vals),label='r3')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

But for some reason the solutions for the the two firsts roots are mixed before `~ .72`. I have no idea how to correct this, make then not mix

Comment: Why come so close to including runnable code but then not actually make it runnable by leaving out the most important line (the equation to be solved)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behavior is to be expected with Numpy, as you are going trough a complex branch cut. In this case you should use Mpmath as the evaluation module for `lambdify`, which deals with branch cuts differently. For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x =e_list[0]
lam_x = lambdify(t, x, modules=['mpmath'])

x_vals = np.linspace(0.01, .9999, 1000, dtype=complex)
y_vals = []
for _x in x_vals:
    y_vals.append(complex(lam_x(_x)))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.real(x_vals), np.real(y_vals),label='r1')


x =e_list[1]
lam_x = lambdify(t, x, modules=['mpmath'])

x_vals = np.linspace(0.01, .9999, 1000, dtype=complex)

y_vals = []
for _x in x_vals:
    y_vals.append(complex(lam_x(_x)))

plt.plot(np.real(x_vals), np.real(y_vals),label='r2')


x =e_list[2]
lam_x = lambdify(t, x, modules=['numpy'])

x_vals = np.linspace(0.01, .9999, 1000, dtype=complex)
y_vals = np.around(lam_x(x_vals),decimals=5)

plt.plot(np.real(x_vals), np.real(y_vals),label='r3')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]